# Nginx subdomain configuration Letsencryt wildcard HTTPS certificate

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain

**What I want to do ?**

I have two application on local ports and I want to access them like that :

- *maindomain.com* -> node.js app
- *sub.maindomain.com* -> .net core app

**My DNS config**

- *maindomain.com* (A Record) `11.111.11.111`
- *sub.maindomain.com* (A Record) `11.111.11.111`

**Nginx config**

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/maindomain.com (linked from ./sites-available/)

```bsh
upstream node_app{
        # node.js running
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server{
    listen 80;
    server_name www.maindomain.com maindomain.com;
    #Redirige toutes les requêtes http vers https
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.com/privkey.pem;

    server_name www.maindomain.com maindomain.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://node_app;
    }
}
```

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub.maindomain.com (linked from /sites-available/)

```bsh
upstream core_api{
        # Asp.net core API running in background
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server{
    listen 80;
    server_name www.sub.maindomain.com sub.maindomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/maindomain.com/privkey.pem;

    server_name www.sub.maindomain.com sub.maindomain.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://core_api;
    }
}
```

**Result :**
After that, I have restarted my nginx service.
Requests on sub.maindomain.com just redirect on maindomain.com.

What did I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you forgot:

```
server_name www.api-accropolis.maindomain.com api-accropolis.maindomain.com;
```

... in SSL `server` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub.maindomain.com`

And you also forgot:

```
server_name www.maindomain.com maindomain.com;
```

... in SSL `server` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/maindomain.fr`

Comment: I have changes some values in my exemple.
And i forgot to say that the ``/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/maindomain.fr`` working well. 
According to the documentation i can specify server_name only in the http server

Comment: Those are *all* HTTP servers, some with TLS support and some are not. You have to specify `server_name` within every `server` unless you're doing something fancy.

Comment: I did it, nothing changed, the syntax is good but the behaviour is the same